# How can I clone a module from linux kernel?

Tags: linux, git, github

If I only want to focus on a module of `linux`, such as `perf`, how can I just fork or download `perf` module related files from [github](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/tools/perf)? I have tried the following command:

```
c:\work> git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/tools/perf
Cloning into 'perf'...
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/tools/perf/' not found
```

But it can't work.

Comment: This is not possible as the entire linux repo is just ONE BIG git repository. You don't have any ways to selectively clone only one folder. You can just clone the entire repository and work on the folder you like.

Comment: It acutally is possible. See my answer below.

Comment: Why do people downvote this? It's a good question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a combination of two relatively new features of Git.

The first is *sparse-checkout* (available since Git 1.7.0). Sparse-checkout allows you to keep your workspace clean by explicitely specifying which directories you want to have in your repo. However it does not affect the size of the whole repository and downloading 1GB of all Linux kernel sources is pain in the neck. That's why you need the second feature:

The second feature is *shallow clone* (available since Git 1.9.0). It allows you to pull from a repo keeping only *n* changesets in the history using `--depth` parameter.

So if you want to get only the `tools/perf` module this is the way to go:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo "tools/perf" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull --depth=1 origin master
```

Voila! The only directory in your repo is `tools/perf` and you had to download only 136MB.

Comment: This method doesn't keep all the logs about `tools/perf`, so is there any method to keep the logs too?

Comment: If you want all the logs just skip the `--depth=1` option, but you will download the whole history so it is a lot of data to download. Or you can try, for example, `--depth=4000` which will download logs for the latest 4000 commits only.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Luboš' answer, since I also needed only perf, but a specific tagged version. The tags don't appear in the shallow clone. So you need to check out the repo exactly at the tagged version.

Replace

```sh
git pull --depth=1 origin master
```

with

```
git fetch --depth=1 origin v4.19
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
```

if the version you want is 4.19.

If you want to actually build that specific perf version you'll need more folders:

```sh
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo "tools/perf" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "tools/scripts" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "tools/build" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "tools/include" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "tools/include" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "tools/arch" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "tools/lib" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git fetch --depth=1 origin v4.19
git checkout FETCH_HEAD
make -C tools/perf
```

Now (if you have all the dependencies installed):

```sh
$ ./tools/perf/perf --version
perf version 4.19.g84df
```